# ImeAction Search is changed to Done after tapping on it

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an Edittext for searching on Listview.

I have set `imeOption` to 'IME_ACTION_SEARCH' so that soft-keyboard will show search key on it.

The problem is that when I tap on search key on keyboard if edittext contains no text in it, the search key changes to 'Done' instead of dismissing the keyboard.

If the Edittext contains some text in it the search key works well.

[image: Keyboard before tapping on Search]

[image: Keyboard after tapping Search]

Comment: have you done IME_ACTION_SEARCH programmatically?

Comment: Yes. I tried both programmatically and  through xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem behind this. It was happening because the `OnEditorAction` Listener was not properly set on Edittext. Since listener was not properly set call was not reaching `onEditorAction()` method.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML layout file you can set

```
<EditText android:imeOptions="actionSearch" />
```

Or in your Java source file you could do

```
yourTextField.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
```

Then you can override the listener for the search event.

```
yourTextField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) { 
            //if textfield value is empty then close keyboard.
            //else call your search function.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Same thing I implemented in my app.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this to your edittext in xml

```
     android:imeOptions="actionSearch|actionSearch"
```

this will show you search button always!

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I fixed it by -

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
                /* First check that if the edit text is empty or not */
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(myEditText.getText().toString()) && actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                /* Do your task here */
            }
            return true; /* Must return true because here we customize the action */
        });
```

According to this [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener),

> Return true if you have consumed the action, else false.

So we need to return **true** here because we customize the action here and it will prevent change. Also, be ensured that your `EditText` is containing the flag -

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```