# Load webpage without clicking any button

Tags: java, android, webview

I have read many tutorial for creating an Android browser. Every tutorial shows an example of a EditText & a Button. User will write URL in that EditText and finally they will click on Go Button. But I want that webpage will be load without clicking on Go Button like every modern browser(eg. Chrome). They will see a Button in their keyboard named "Go" while they are writing URL.
But how to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to have custom button text on keyboard?

Comment: I am newbie in Android development. So, some of your question may be difficult for me. I am giving an example. Go to Chrome browser. Click on input url and write your url. Then chevk your keyboard. There's an button named Go in bottom-right. I want this button for my browser's input URL EditText.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18895053/3931968) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML layout add this

```
<EditText 
    .........
    android:imeOptions="actionGo" />
```

And in JAVA file just set the listener like this

```
yourTextField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) { 
            //if textfield value is empty then close keyboard.
            //else call your search function.
        }
    }
});
```